# How to get the Current Active Tab Name inside app.module in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

My App has sidemenu + tabs and structure is similar to 
https://devdactic.com/ionic-side-menu-tabs/

Menu.ts is the root of my App and it is within that module which I'm loading the Tabs Pages

I want to get the current active tab inside app.component's constructor and I've tried the below methods and few others

```
this.nav.getActive().component
this.nav.getActive().component.tabRef.getSelected().root

like this
    this.app.viewDidEnter.subscribe((evt) => {
this.nav.getActive().component

    });
```

None of it is working. It always returns TabsPage instead of the current active Page name.

Tabs Page

```
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root: any = 'HomePage';
  tab2Root: any = 'ProductsPage';
  tab3Root: any = 'DynamicProductsPage';
  myIndex: number;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.myIndex = navParams.data.tabIndex || 0;
  }

}
```

Tabs Template

```
<ion-tabs  #myTabs [selectedIndex]="myIndex" [color]="'primary'">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root"  tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="ios-home" show=true  md="md-home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root"  tabTitle="Products" tabIcon="ios-laptop" show=true md="md-laptop"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below.

```
export class TabsPage {

@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

ionViewDidEnter() {
  let tab:Tab = this.tabRef.getSelected();//Returns the currently selected tab
 }

}
```

You can read more about [**it here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/).

If you need to send this details to the `app.component.ts` then just use [**Events**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/). Using `Events` you can send above details (i.e. `tab`) to the `app.component.ts`.

Comment: The above code will work on TabsPage but I want to get the the active tab inside app.component.

@Sampath I've checked your profile and looks like you've quite a lot knowledge about Ionic 3. I'm only starting it and this is my first app.

Have you encountered an issue with the hardware backbuton not working correctly when using sidemenu+tabs together? I'm trying to such an issue and for that I need to get the current active page. If you know someway please let me know. 

Hope you'll understand

Comment: You just need to fire `Event` here: Send that details through that event. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

Comment: That is not my requirement. I really want to get the current active tab's name inside app.component. I need this to work to make another thing work :(

Comment: I cannot see any other method to get the `tabs` details within the `app.component.ts` due to the components architecture other than the `Events`.

Answer (score 0):

> page/tab.ts

```
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Page1 } from '../page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../page2/page2';
import { GlobalvarProvider } from "../../providers/globalvar/globalvar";

export class TabPage{

    tab1Root = Page1;
    tab2Root = Page2;

    parm1="page1";
    parm2="page2";

    constructor(private navParams: NavParams,private GlobalvarProvider: GlobalvarProvider){
        this.GlobalvarProvider.setActiveTab(navParams.get('index'));
    }

}
```

> page/tab.html

```
<ion-tabs color="secondary1" selectedIndex= {{index}} >
    <ion-tab [root]="Page1" [rootParams]="parm1" tabTitle="Page1" tabIcon="ff-lunch" ></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="Page2" [rootParams]="parm2" tabTitle="Page2" tabIcon="ff-lunch" ></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

> providers/globalvar.ts

```
export class GlobalvarProvider {
    private active_tab:any;

    constructor(){
        this.active_tab=null;
    }

    setActiveTab(val){
        this.active_tab=val;
    }
    getActiveTab(){
        return this.active_tab;
    }
}
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { GlobalvarProvider } from "../providers/globalvar/globalvar";
export class MyApp {

    constructor(private GlobalvarProvider: GlobalvarProvider){

    }
     initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then((source) => {

        console.log(this.GlobalvarProvider.getActiveTab());

        }
    }
}
```